# Symfony2: Use different form types in a collection based on sent data

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, fosrestbundle

I have several entities that inherit from a base `Widget`.

In a form I have the field `widgets` which is a collection. This form is based on an entity, which has a `1:n` relationship to `Widget`. What I want to do is (based on the sent data in `widgets`) to create a specific subclass to validate and create the actual object.

In the form I defined the field like this:

```
$builder->add('widgets', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new WidgetType(),
    'allow_add' => true
));
```

So for example I have two subsclasses, `ImageWidget` and `MapWidget`. I created `FormTypes` for these two entities and now the client is sending the following data (I am using FOSRestBundle):

```
...
"widgets": [
    {
        "widget_type": "map",
        "stationId": 543647
    },
    {
        "widget_type": "image",
        "image": "data:image/png;data,...."
    }
]
```

And based on the property `widget_type` (which is the property used by Doctrine to differentiate between the widget types in the database), I want the form to create a `MapWidgetType` for the first entry and a `ImageWidgetType` for the second one.

Is this possible to to?

I am using Symfony 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bundle should solve your problem: https://github.com/infinite-networks/InfiniteFormBundle#polycollection